# Clear all previous mouse clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, events, click, mouse

I have a form that has a child form. I perform some mouse actions in the parent form before I open the child form. The function of the child form is to capture a mouse click and draw a circle with the centre in the clicked point.
The problem is that when the child form loads, a circle is already drawn in the top left corner of the form, before I have a chance to click the mouse.
I suppose the paint event fires and uses a mouse click that was performed in the parent form.
Please advise about how to clear the mouse clicks queue when the child form is entered.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"how to clear the mouse clicks queue"_ - that would arguably lead to a poor user experience.  They might think their mouse is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much easier solution: In the child form constructor I added these two statements:
_newCenterPointXCoordinate = -1;
_newCenterPointYCoordinate = -1;

and the Paint events handler is:

```
private void Form_Child_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphicsObject = e.Graphics;
        float blackPenWidth = 3;
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, blackPenWidth);

        string fontFamilyName = "Times New Roman";
        float fontSize = 25.2F;
        FontStyle _fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
        GraphicsUnit graphicsUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
        byte gdiCharSet = ((byte)(0));
        Font textFont = new Font(fontFamilyName, fontSize, _fontStyle, graphicsUnit, gdiCharSet);
        Color textColor = Color.Black;
        if (_newCenterPointXCoordinate > 0 && _newCenterPointYCoordinate > 0)
        {
            graphicsObject.DrawEllipse(blackPen, _newCenterPointXCoordinate - _newRadius, _newCenterPointYCoordinate - _newRadius, _newRadius * 2, _newRadius * 2);
            using (StringFormat stringFormatting = new StringFormat())
            {
                stringFormatting.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                stringFormatting.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                graphicsObject.DrawString(_nodeNumber.ToString(), textFont, new SolidBrush(textColor), _centerPoint, stringFormatting);
            }

            this.Invalidate(); // Force a form repaint event.
        }
        _newCenterPointXCoordinate = -1;
        _newCenterPointYCoordinate = -1;

        // Dispose of objects.
        blackPen.Dispose();
        graphicsObject.Dispose();
    }
```

thus disregarding any residual centre point coordinates.